# How can I debug my SNS subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-sns, lets-encrypt

I have created a basic SNS topic.  It's a HTTP (and HTTPS) request a an endpoint on my web server.  The web server is not on AWS.

The endpoint the SNS subscription points to sends me an email containing all of the headers of the request.  Even if the headers are empty and email will be sent.  A request of any kind will result in an email.

The endpoint will process the request regardless of the HTTP verb used (GET, POST, etc).

If I visit the endpoint in my browser, I receive an email.  When I try to request a confirmation within the AWS control panel, I get nothing.

I thought this could be down to me using a Let's Encrypt SSL, but I have also tried using a HTTP endpoint, rather than HTTPS, but get the same issue.

How can I debug this?  Is there any way of seeing why the request is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to debug http web hooks and such like this, I use this tool:

https://ngrok.com/

to setup a public endpoint that points to my local web server, that I am running in my development environment, so I can see the request come in, and depending on the language (usually .net for me), I can step thru the code as the request is received in my debugger. You'll need to temporarily point your sns topic to this endpoint.

This won't help if you are not getting the request at all, but if there is any question that the request is coming in, but its not being processed correctly, this may help.

Comment: ngrok helped.  Turned out to be cached routes in my Laravel app on the server I was testing on... otherwise known as human-error.  Thanks